# Insert emails into a table using SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into a table, but I am getting the exception **java.lang.NullPointerException** in the line

> ih.bind(coldesc,message);

. I do not know if the problem is my databaHelper or  in my method.

Here is my retrieveEmails method to pull down all the email from GMAIL and insert the non multipart emails into a table that works perfectly until `ih.bind(coldesc,message);`:

```
public void retrieveEmails(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.pop3.host" , "pop.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.pop3.user" , username);
    // Start SSL connection
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory" , 995 );
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
    props.put("mail.pop3.port" , 995);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
        @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication( username , password);
                }
    });
    try {
        Store store  = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop.gmail.com", 995 , username , password);
        Folder fldr = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        fldr.open(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);

        int totalMsg = fldr.getMessageCount();
        int unread = fldr.getUnreadMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Total MSG: " + totalMsg + " unreaed: " + unread  );

        Message[] messages = fldr.getMessages();
        //Message[] msg = fldr.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
        Message[] msg = messages;

        System.out.print("size " + messages .length);
        if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");


        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());

            if(messages[i].getSubject().contains("Order")){
                System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());
                Object content = messages[i].getContent();

                Object objRef = msg[i].getContent();
                if (!(objRef instanceof Multipart)) {
                   String message =((String)content).replace("<br />", "").replace("<strong>", "").replace("</strong>", "").replace("<div>", "").replace("<h1>", "");
                   message = message.replace("</div>", "").replace("</h1>", "");
                   System.out.print(message);  


                   InsertHelper ih = null;
                    try {
                        ih = new InsertHelper(db, DatabaseHelper.table);
                        final int coldesc = ih.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.column);
                        ih.bind(coldesc,message);
                        ih.execute();

                         db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                         Log.e("","Inserted");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (ih != null)
                            ih.close();
                        if (db != null) {
                            db.endTransaction();
                            // db.close();
                        }
                    }

                   //return;
                }
                else{
                    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) objRef;

                    //Multipart multipart = (Multipart) msg[i].getContent();

                    for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount()-1; x++) {
                        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);

                        String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

                        if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                            System.out.println("Mail have some attachment : ");

                            DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
                            System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(bodyPart.getContent());
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }

        fldr.close(true);
        store.close();

        Log.d("Store", "Store was closed");


    } catch(Exception exc) {
        Log.e("",exc.toString());
    }

}
```

Here my database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String table = "tblorder";
  public static final String column = "description";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static DatabaseHelper instance;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + table + "("+ column
      + "  nvarchar(20) NULL);";

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);
    onCreate(db);
  }


    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            return instance;

    }

}
```

here is the stack trace:

```
        03-26 10:20:39.200: W/System.err(17132): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-26 10:20:39.210: W/System.err(17132):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.bind(DatabaseUtils.java:1166)
    03-26 10:20:39.210: W/System.err(17132):    at com.example.gmailreceiver.MainActivity.retrieveEmails(MainActivity.java:247)
    03-26 10:20:39.220: W/System.err(17132):    at com.example.gmailreceiver.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:176)
    03-26 10:20:39.225: W/System.err(17132):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3660)
    03-26 10:20:39.230: W/System.err(17132):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14398)
    03-26 10:20:39.235: W/System.err(17132):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    03-26 10:20:39.240: W/System.err(17132):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-26 10:20:39.245: W/System.err(17132):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-26 10:20:39.250: W/System.err(17132):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    03-26 10:20:39.255: W/System.err(17132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-26 10:20:39.255: W/System.err(17132):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-26 10:20:39.255: W/System.err(17132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
    03-26 10:20:39.260: W/System.err(17132):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
    03-26 10:20:39.260: W/System.err(17132):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: On which line is the NullPouinterException thrown? It would help to post the stack trace too...

Comment: Do you want us to guess where the exception is happening? We aren't psychic. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Thank you guys...I am getting the exception in the line  "ih.bind(coldesc,message);"

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak the stacktrace has been posted.

Comment: What value is ih.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.column); returning?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak it returns "1" and the message is not null either....

Comment: Did you try ih.prepareForReplace()/prepareForInsert() before the bind?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak...the  ih.prepareForInsert() solved my problem...thank you